# cant login on heroku using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

User can sign up and redirect to show page thats work fine in development mode but on heroku when sign up it create the user but after that instead of redirect to profile it will go on sign in page. And if i signed in the user with credentials it will not signed in. i have inspect after doing this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :check_current_user
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

 def show
 end

 def check_current_user
    user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    puts 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' , user.inspect
  end
 end
```

and check_current_user give me current user "nil"

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed Devise standard behaviour, of course you have `current_user` nil during `check_current_user`, that's because that filter is called BEFORE the Devise filter `:authenticate_user!` in which it sets the `current_user` variable.
Just try to swap the two filters like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :check_current_user
```

Also, by default, Devise don't put any `user_id` in the session, so the method should be something like:

```
def check_current_user
  puts 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' , current_user.inspect
end
```

Not sure it will fix all your problem, but at least is a starting point :)
If you still can't get it working, add something to your question so we can help further.